# Open detached OLE binary in native application

Tags: c++, ole

I have some OLE binaries detached from RTF document.  For example OLE binaries belong to MS Word.  This OLE binaries are in FAT32 compound storage format. I am trying to load this binaries in native app using C++ ole headers.

I'm able to get IStorage object from binary using stgopenstorageex but when I try to call OleLoad method, error "Class not registered" is thrown.

Does anyone have any idea on how to proceed?

Comment: Sure, call GetClassFile() using the name of the file to see what object OLE thinks the file represents.

Also, open the storage and call ReadClassStg() on it to get the CLSID of the object OLE thinks is in the file.


After you get the CLSID(s), verify that there is a server registered to handle it.

Comment: @JoeWillcoxson thanx for your comment. Please check my update. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I made some progress today. 
Problem with the "Class not registered" error was resolved by opening "Word.Document.8" storage in IStorage object and then calling OleLoad on "Word.Document.8" storage.

I now have IOleObject. 
If I call DoWerb method, MS Word opens and shows document. 
This is good progress.

Now I would like to get COM handle to this document. 
Idea is to load the document in MS Word hidden (headless) and save it to disk as doc,  docx or PDF.

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Have no idea what you mean by "COM handle"...  Once you have an object, you can query for the IDispatch interface.  From the IDispatch interface you can call the SaveAs method.  Easiest way in C++ is to use CComDispatchDriver and it's Invoke1 method to specify L"SaveAs" as the method, and then the filename as the second argument.

Comment: @JoeWillcoxson
Well I am trying to get IDispatch interface but error is thrown: "E_NOINTERFACE No such interface supported."

This is my line: result = oleObj->QueryInterface(IID_IDispatch, (void**)&disp);

Comment: Maybe try calling OleRun before calling IDispatch?  Sometimes when the object is not in a running state, the QI will fail because the proxy stub doesn't know about interface implemented by the object.

Comment: @JoeWillcoxson DUDE, YOU ARE OLE GOD. OleRun did the trick. I will now check what methods I have at disposal. Thank you very much.